# How to send multiple data for live username & phone checking?

Tags: php, ajax

I want to post two variables (username & phone) to a post.php page.

> Here is my code:( The variables are declared as phone & username)

```
    <script>
    function checkAvailabilityemail() {
        $("#loaderIcon").show();
        $("#dbutton").hide();
var phone = $("#phone").val();
    var username = $("#username").val();
        jQuery.ajax({
        url: "newton/check_availability_button.php",
        data: {
    phone : phone,
    username : username
    },
        type: "POST",
        success:function(data){
            $("#user-availability-status-button").show();
            $("#user-availability-status-button").html(data);
            $("#loaderIcon").hide();
        },
        error:function (){}
        });
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: please specify error you do get..

Comment: inside your function define phone and username variable.

Comment: The page is getting hanged. If i pass a single value using `data:'pan='+$("#pan").val(),` then it is working fine. But in the case of multiple values, it is getting hanged.

Comment: I have updated the code but even then it isnt working and showing the same result. This time the page is not getting hanged. But the preloader is  not showing up and the post is not taking place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify you code like

```
<script>
function checkAvailabilityemail() {
    var phone = '1023129837';
    var username = 'username';
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: "newton/check_availability_button.php",
    data: {
phone : phone,
username : username
},
    type: "POST",
    success:function(data){
        alert(data)
    },
    error:function (){}
    });
}
</script>
```

in your `check_availability_button.php` file type print_r($_POST); and then check both variable are in alert. Then you can dynamic your two variable.